# Writing hebrew to file turns to gibberish when run from exported jar

Tags: java, encoding, jar

I have a small program that writes some Hebrew letters and some numbers to a file, written in JAVA.
The Hebrew is written fine when i run the program from Eclipse, but if i export it into an executable JAR file and run it from there the Hebrew turns to gibberish

My code:

```
if (content.length() > 0) {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(content);
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

I have also tried using an OutputStreamWriter to set the encoding myself:

```
if (content.length() > 0) {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter
        (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "windows-1255"));
    bufferedWriter.write(content);
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

The encodings i tried:

- ISO-8859-8
- windows-1255
- x-IBM856
- IBM862
- IBM424
- UTF-8

Some of them return proper Hebrew when i run the program from eclipse but all of them turn the Hebrew to different types of gibberish when run from the JAR file.
I am not even sure the encoding in the code itself is the issue or the way to fix it.

I am running the JAR using a batch file on windows 10.
My java version info:

- java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

example of output when using UTF-8

A line from the Hebrew file (generated by eclipse):

```
210001         188      13 04/09/1804/09/18                                            50.00         1           123456789  לירון קטלן                               הרא"ה 291                                     רמת גן                                                                     6013
```

The same line from the gibberish file (generated from the JAR):

```
210001         188      13 04/09/1804/09/18                                            50.00         1           123456789  ×œ×™×¨×•×Ÿ ×§×˜×œ×Ÿ                               ×”×¨×�"×” 291                                     ×¨×ž×ª ×’×Ÿ                                                                     6013
```

Don't mind the extra white-spaces, they are supposed to be there.

Comment: why don't you use UTF-8? to my understanding, it should support Hebrew script

Comment: UTF-8 is standard on more machines these days.

Comment: Tried UTF-8 as well, it works when running from eclipse but turns out gibrish when running from JAR (same as windows-1255), updated the question

Comment: BTW, this probably doesn't cause your problem but closing BufferedWriter doesn't flush or close the underlying writer. You need to flush or close the underlying writer explicitly to get it flushed. I'm not sure why you would even need a BW as you're going to close the stream immediately after the write anyway.

Comment: As i mentioned and edited in the question, i have tried using UTF-8.
It writes proper Hebrew if i run the program from eclipse, it changes to gibrish only when i run it as a JAR file.

Comment: So your viewer shows the contents of the file as Hebrew or gibberish depending on how you wrote the file? Am I understanding that right? What are you using to view the file?

Comment: I have two files, one created directly from eclipse and one from the JAR file. I am importing them into some program. I can import the first file and it would import the Hebrew correctly but would import gibberish if i import the second file created from the JAR. I use notepad++ to view them but as you can see the file just doesn't write correctly when run from the JAR. It's not a viewing problem since the import works fine on the first file.

Comment: "Gibberish" is a vague term that doesn't provide enough info to understand how it failed. A hex dump might help, once for success, once failure.

Comment: I edited the question to include an example of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code snippet with explicit encoding is correctly crossplatform.

Check that the content is fine Unicode:

```
String content="\u200F\u05D0\u05D1\u05D2\u05D3\u05D4\u200E"; // "אבגדהו"
```

I used u-encoding so the java source is ASCII and hence the encoding of the java compiler and the encoding of the editor should the erroneously differ, cannot cause
corrupt strings.

Assuming that `content` is a String:

```
if (!content.isEmpty()) {
    content = "\uFEFF" + content; // Add a BOM char in front for Windows
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    Files.write(p, Collections.singletonList(content), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This writes a UTF-8 file that will cause the least of problems, unless inside Israel, where one might assume a country specific encoding, windows-1255.

I added a BOM character as first character of the file, so Windows can easily identify the file, not as some ANSI single-byte encoding, but as UTF-8 Unicode.

Then there rests the problem of representing Hebrew text. There must be an adequate font.

You might opt for writing an HTML file:

```
content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="he">"
    + "<head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head>"
    + "<body><pre>"
    + content.replace("&", "&amp;")
             .replace("<", "&lt;")
             .replace(">", "&gt")
    + "</pre></body></html>";
```

I find that better than writing a BOM.

The last thing is to add LTR ('\u200E') and RTL (Right-To-Left, '\u200F') mark chars, but I take it, that that gives no problem.

---

It always is that at some place an overloaded method is used, where the encoding is not present, defaulting to the current platform encoding.

Do

```
new InputStreamReader(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

and such.

Comment: I tried adding the BOM character, but to no avail. My problem isn't viewing this file or displaying it somewhere, i am taking this file and importing it into a different program. If i import the file generated directly from eclipse the Hebrew is fine, if i import the one created from the JAR its all gibberish, Viewing these files have the same effect, but that's not really the issue, it's like the Hebrew wasn't written as Hebrew when the file was created when run from the JAR

Comment: Managed to find the problem thanks to your comments, the problem was my InputStreamReader creation, it was missing the encoding i used in the writer.
`InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` is what fixed it.
If you want to edit your answer to include this I'll mark it as the right answer, or i can answer myself, let me know :)

Comment: I am happy you found the error. Actually this error was more or less mentioned in the initial comments, but it is quite easy to be trapped by such things.

Comment: I accidentally flagged the most helpful comment here, is there a way to undo it?